# Stop a network receiver thread

Tags: java, android

Assume I have an object of type `NetThread` (defined below), called `nt`. I have initialized and started it

```
nt = new NetThread(port, rs); 
nt.setDaemon(true); 
nt.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY); 
nt.start();
```

Now I want to be able to stop this thread at any point during its execution. I can do this by calling `nt.interrupt()`.

However, I thought I would try to do something that made more sense to me: create a method within `NetThread` called `StopListening()`.

While `nt` is running, I call `nt.StopListening()`. Nothing.

**The thread just keeps running.  What did I miss?  Why doesn't this work?**

```
public class NetThread extends Thread {

    int port; 

    private static int PAYLOAD_MAX = 10000; 
    private static int NET_SO_TIMEOUT = 0; 
    private RunStats rs; 

    private boolean stopflag = false; 

    private StageCode stage; 

    NetThread(int port_number, RunStats runstats)
    {
        rs = runstats; 
        port = port_number; 
        stage = StageCode.STAGE_WAIT; 
    }

    public synchronized void stopListening()
    {
        Log.d(C.DTAG, "stopListening() was called..."); 
        stopflag=true; 
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        receiveData(); 
        Log.d(C.DTAG, "Network thread is finished."); 
    }

    public void receiveData()
    {
        // request permission to do network operations in manifest file...done

        Log.d(C.DTAG, "network thread has started."); 

        // start the network side of things
        DatagramSocket sock = null; 
        DatagramPacket pkt = null; 

        try 
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[PAYLOAD_MAX]; 
            sock = new DatagramSocket(port); 
            sock.setSoTimeout(NET_SO_TIMEOUT);
            pkt = new DatagramPacket(data, 0, PAYLOAD_MAX); 

            while (!stopflag)
            {
                Thread.sleep(0); // allow for an interrupt
                try 
                {
                    sock.receive(pkt); 
                    int length = pkt.getLength(); 
                    processPayload(pkt.getData(), length); 
                }
                catch (InterruptedIOException e)
                {
                    // thrown when a timeout occurs
                    Log.d(C.DTAG, "net: no packets yet"); 
                }
            }
            Log.d(C.DTAG, "done receiving."); 
            if (sock != null) sock.close(); 
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException x) 
        {
            Log.d(C.DTAG, "net: was interrupted."); 
        } 
        catch (SocketException e) 
        {
            Log.d(C.DTAG, "net: SocketException"); 
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            Log.d(C.DTAG, "net: IOException"); 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (sock != null) sock.close(); 
    }

    public void processPayload(byte[] data, int length)
    {
        if (length < 20) return; 

        int sc =    data[ 0] & 0x000000FF | data[ 1]<<8 & 0x0000FF00 | data[ 2]<<16 & 0x00FF0000 | data[ 3]<<24 & 0xFF000000; 
        int seq =   data[ 4] & 0x000000FF | data[ 5]<<8 & 0x0000FF00 | data[ 6]<<16 & 0x00FF0000 | data[ 7]<<24 & 0xFF000000; 
        int i =     data[ 8] & 0x000000FF | data[ 9]<<8 & 0x0000FF00 | data[10]<<16 & 0x00FF0000 | data[11]<<24 & 0xFF000000; 
        int s =     data[12] & 0x000000FF | data[13]<<8 & 0x0000FF00 | data[14]<<16 & 0x00FF0000 | data[15]<<24 & 0xFF000000; 
        int n =     data[16] & 0x000000FF | data[17]<<8 & 0x0000FF00 | data[18]<<16 & 0x00FF0000 | data[19]<<24 & 0xFF000000; 

        StageCode sc2 = null; 
        switch (sc)
        {
        case 20: sc2 = StageCode.STAGE_INIT; break; 
        case 30: sc2 = StageCode.STAGE_TEST; break; 
        case 40: sc2 = StageCode.STAGE_STOP; break; 
        }

        TestPacketHeader tph = new TestPacketHeader(sc2, seq, i, s, n); 
        rs.RegisterReceivedPacket(tph); 

        if (sc2 == StageCode.STAGE_STOP) stopflag = true; 
    }

    public synchronized StageCode status()
    {
        return stage; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are trying to do it is essentially recreating what interrupt does behind the scenes so you are probably better off just using interrupt. Having said that if you make the boolean `volatile` so the threads will see changes other threads make your code should work. :)

Interrupt also has the advantage that it will wake your thread up if it is in certain wait states and so will tend to cause the interrupt to process faster. Note that this cannot be completely relied on though as the interrupt may be received between checking the flag and entering the wait state - and in that case the wait will still need to time out before the flag is seen.

Both interrupt and your own version of it work by signalling the Thread that it should stop and then letting the Thread shut itself down tidily. That is the correct way to do things, as just aggressively killing threads can lead to all sorts of nasty side effects such as half-completed processing.

Comment: Can you please also say, why it is better? I always use `while(!isInterrupted())` and call `myThread.interrupt();`. It works just fine

Comment: Actually you are right, I was thinking of an asynchronous kill which isn't what interrupt does.

Comment: Thumbs up. Additionally I'd like to say that I like using `Thread.interrupt()` since it wakes the thread up. I often have cases where this leads to (in my opinion) better behaviour.

Comment: Yes, I was just thinking I should mention that MalaKa, I've also mentioned the main limitation of that.

Comment: Okay, so the volatile tip from Tim solved half the problem. The other half was solved when I realized that NET_SO_TIMEOUT=0 meant that the loop hung forever on the line that receives the packet. I set NET_SO_TIMEOUT=500, and then within 500 ms of the time I call stopListening(), the execution would actually reach the loop condition (!stopflag). Duh. Thanks guys